# ssh refuses key when home directory is owned by different group and given full permissions

Tags: ssh

So I came across an odd issue with ssh. It's not exactly a show stopper, but was wondering why it happens.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I have ssh set up the standard way, with the keys in:

```
/home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And has permissions `myuser:myuser` /w `755`

Now to break it, if I run:

```
chown myuser:mysql /home/myuser/
chmod 775 /home/myuser/
```

I get the `server refused our key` error, and within the auth.log, I see this:

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/myuser
```

But, if I now change the mode so that the group doesn't have write permissions:

```
chmod 755 /home/myuser/
```

It works fine Lol ...
Anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is hardcoded in the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/1dc8d93ce69d6565747eb44446ed117187621b26/auth.c#L505). These three lines checks that your home directory is owned by you and nobody else can write in it:

```
if (stat(buf, &st) < 0 ||
    (!platform_sys_dir_uid(st.st_uid) && st.st_uid != uid) ||
    (st.st_mode & 022) != 0) {
```

This is pretty reasonable request since you really don't want anybody touching your home directory (usually not even reading), but never writing, since it would mean that anybody from that group could add his key into your `authorized_keys` file (or do other harm) and login as you, which you basically don't want.

Comment: Awesome, everyday's a school day :D